# How to switch to ubuntu only from windows 10 on ssd without losing data on the second hard drive?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, installation, backup

My laptop has ssd and hdd both. I want to switch to linux but I don't want to lose any data. So I will transfer all the data in the hard disk drive and install ubuntu on ssd. In this case, will I lose the data on hdd as well? How to install ubuntu without losing that data?
In the end, I want to use ssd and hdd both on my laptop. With all the backup data in my hdd safe.

Comment: Normally you won't, but as you can never tell for sure if yourself / the installer will do crap, the safest way is certainly disconnecting the HDD before installing.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be 100% safe, disconnect the hdd while installing ubuntu on the ssd.

Remember to check that the filesystem used on the hdd is supported by ubuntu.